# навигация по словарю

Tags: python, json, словари

Здравствуйте.

Из json получаю словарь, большой, развесистый.
И чтобы получить нужное значение приходится писать такой код:

```
url = data['b-500px']['today']['slide']['appropriate']['url']
```

Есть ли возможность упростить доступ к ключам?
Например, писать все через точку: `data["b-500px.today.slide.appropriate.url"]`

Или, быть может, сразу получить нужный ключ: data['//url'] ?

Comment: похожий (более сложный) вопрос (с поддержкой изменения словаря): [Python: Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке для работы как со словарями, так и с JSON такой функциональности нет. То, что вам скорее всего нужно, -- какая-либо вариация JSON query language, например, [objectpath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objectpath/).

Answer (score 1):

Из коробки в Python такой возможности нет. Потребуются дополнительные действия.

Кроме собственно модуля ''objecpath'', упомянутого Вадимом,
можно обойтись ручным решением, основанным на `reduce`:

```
def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], mapList, dataDict)

def setInDict(dataDict, mapList, value):
    getFromDict(dataDict, mapList[:-1])[mapList[-1]] = value
```

Пример использования:

```
>>> getFromDict(dataDict, ["b", "v", "y"])
2
>>> setInDict(dataDict, ["b", "v", "w"], 4)
```

Естественно, что вместо списка используюшегося в качестве ключа,
можно использовать и строку, если немного переписать функции:
применять к ключу при доступе `split('.')`.

Естественно, что в этом случае ключи не смогут содержать `.` внутри.

Подробнее об этом:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-python-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys

Answer (score 1):

Я использую вот такую вспомогательную функцию (без `reduce` ибо python3+):

```
def get_value(data, keys):
    for key in keys:
        data = data[key]
    return data
```

Где `keys` соответственно список ключей, как в примере Игоря.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то не сильно короче, зато выглядит странно:

```
data['b-500px']['today']['slide']['appropriate']['url']
и
data["b-500px.today.slide.appropriate.url"]
```

Но вообще почему не написать простейший хелпер?

```
class XDict(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.data:
            return XDict(self.data[attr])
        raise AttributeError

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode(self.data)



data = XDict({'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}})

data.a.b
> {'c': 1}

data.a.b.c
> 1
```